# Measuring Current using EmonTx / Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am getting 0 values when trying to measure non invasive current using an EmonTx  (https://wiki.openenergymonitor.org/index.php/EmonTx_V3.4) which is based on an Arduino Uno / ATmega328 microprocessor.

I am using an example sketch from openenergymonitor github and calibrated a few settings:

- Original code - https://github.com/openenergymonitor/emonTxFirmware/blob/master/emonTxV3/noRF/emonTxV3_DirectSerial/emonTxV3_DirectSerial.ino
- Changed voltage calibration to 130 for USA - ct1.voltage(0, 130, 1.7);
- Change current calibration to 50 because I am using a SCT013-050 50A 1V cT sensor ct1.current(1, 50);
- Added current measurement to output - Serial.print(ct1.Irms);

The current measurement is always 0.  Would anyone know what I may be doing wrong here?  I have tried using an electric kettle and an electric heater as they should draw enough current to register a reading.  I have also checked the output of the cT sensor using a multi meter and it is outputting voltage between 0V and 1V as expected.

Serial output values do not change regardless of load.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need to do some scaling for current values?

Comment: From what I understand, the EmonLib does the scaling for you based on the current calibration value provided in ct1.current(1,50).  The calibration information says that if you are using a cT sensor that ourputs 0-1V, then the scaling is the Amp measurement that equates to 1V.  I have read others use a 30A 1V sensor and their calibration value is 30.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming related problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non invasive current sensor needs to be wrapped around live or neutral wire only, not both.  I was testing using a dual core cable that contained both live and neutral.  When I split the wires it worked great.

This article pointed me in the right direction.

http://www.homautomation.org/2013/09/17/current-monitoring-with-non-invasive-sensor-and-arduino/